# PHP extending a namespaced library

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

What are the best practices for extending a library in PHP?

I'm using the [bshaffer OAuth2](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) library. In my code, I instantiate the library like this:

```
//// Start up the OAuth2 server
require_once('./oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
OAuth2\Autoloader::register();
```

All of the OAuth2 classes are under the namespace starting like OAuth2\foo\bar. I am able to extend these classes without specifying a namespace for my own classes by giving them a unique name (which I prefer not to do). However, I would like to create my own namespace in order to keep the actual class names the same when extending them.

For instance, when I try to extend the Pdo class this way, it says 'class Pdo already instantiated'.

```
class Pdo extends OAuth2\Pdo {
}
```

So I tried it this way. In MyServer.php, I have:

```
<?php
  namespace MyNS;
  class Server extends OAuth2\Server {
  }
?>
```

But then I get an error that the *class MyNS\OAuth2\Server does not exist*. Obviously, it doesn't, and I don't think you can go 'up' a level with namespaces like you can with directories.

I've spent a fair amount of time reading the docs for PHP classes. I *can* extend the classes by renaming them (eg MyServer or MyPdo), but this seems messy and I feel like I should use my own name space. Or even MyNS\OAuth2 could work if I knew how to do it that way. Maybe I have to create my own autoloader for the classes (which I don't know how to do yet)?

Can someone please shine a light in my brain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with your own namespace - you just need an extra backslash `\` to ensure that you are referring to the `OAuth2` that is sitting in the [***global space***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php). - ***i.e.***

```php
<?php
    namespace MyNS;
    class Server extends \OAuth2\Server {
        //               ^______________________ here
    }
```

Comment: Figures. The woes of programming, a single slash breaks everything. Thank you SO much. Namespaces have clicked in my brain.